# How to (enable/disable) seeing scrollable content blurred through titlebar on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, scrollview, titlebar

The default behavior when scrolling on macOS is to show a blurred version of the scrolled content through the titlebar. I'm wondering what attribute/setting controls this behavior. In particular I'd like to disable this effect for my document windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that I can disable the effect app wide by setting the `NSScrollViewShouldScrollUnderTitlebar` defaults key to false.

I've also found that you can disable the effect for a particular documentView (presented in scroll view) by overriding `- (BOOL)_wantsUnderTitlebarView;` and returning false. Or you can disable in by creating a custom the NSScrollView and having `- (BOOL)_canAddUnderTitlebarView;` return false.

This solves the problem, though in a hacky way. Still looking for the proper way to disable this feature.